# My Ibanez TMB100 sounds input cut in and out and fuzzes

Tags: bass-guitar, electric-bass-guitar

For some reason after not playing my Ibanez TMB100 bass, the sound cuts on and off most especially playing the lower strings. I checked the jack cable but with a different one it doesn't fix anything.

Could it be the 9V battery? I bought it a few months ago and it was all working fine since yesterday. No drop or shock whatsoever.

It's having the same issue with a little Orange Amp and even more so with an iRig HD2 connected to my mac.

[Video with sound](https://tempclip.com/en/eIFsIiSWYmbfl8K/watch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've left the jack in, the battery is probably below 9v, and it might have been borderline before. Worth replacing, and also use switch cleaner when plugging in all the jacks to their sockets. Move the jacks in and out a good few times, as dirty contacts will cause such effects.

Comment: Eureka, that makes total sense as sometimes it's left in! Probably not wise though. Thanks for this enlightening. I'll replace the 9V battery tomorrow and see if it fixes it.

Comment: that was definitely that! Works fine now. Thank you again!

Comment: Good! Just remember to unplug the bass after every session! And keep a 9v battery in the bass case, just in case, for next time..

Answer (score 2):

I guess you might have a loose contact somewhere in there, and the vibrations caused by the low strings are just enough to occasionally let you loose contact. You might try to remove the pickguard and to carefully look if there is a loose solder connection somewhere, or if moving any of the cable causes that problem. You might also try if tapping or shaking the bass with some force does also cause this problem.